# li tag when hover won't underline

Tags: html, css

Hi guys i'm having a small issue with my li tags when using a link as i'm trying to make it underline when hovering over them but for some reason I can't seem to get it working. Can anyone see where i'm going wrong here?

Thanks

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f6f4fb;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

#name {
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#name a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}

#headerButtons {
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #999;
}

#headerButtons ul {
  margin: 0;
}

#headerButtons li {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-top: 30px
}

#headerButtons a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
}

#headerButtons a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="IMAGES/Logo.svg" width="50px" height="50px">
  </div>
  <div id="name">
    <a href="index.php">
      <p>Project Archive</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="headerButtons">
    <ul>
      <a href="Login.php">
        <li>Register</li>
      </a>
      <a href="Register.php">
        <li>Login</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put the anchor tags inside the li and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to HTML specification its not valid to add anchor inside the
>   ul tag
>
> *Correct way would be, You put all the anchor tag inside the li tag. So, that your css get applied to the text node properly*.

Although the above reason is not why your style is not applied.

Below is the explaination why the browser is not adding the style.

Your HTML structure has li tag inside anchor tag

```
<a href="Login.php">
    <li>Register</li>
</a>
```

and you are trying to underline the text in your css on hover of anchor tag.

```
#headerButtons a:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This will not work. As, your anchor tag have li node and not a text node so the css `text-decoration: underline;` style is not applied.

You have to select the li tag on hover of the anchor node to apply the css to the text node.

**To do this Add this css** (I won't recommend using this approach.)

```
 #headerButtons a:hover>li {
    text-decoration: underline;
 }
```

**SNIPPET**

*(you should not use this snippet use the next one below).*

*This snippet is just to demonstrate that style can be applied. You should use the next snippet.*

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f6f4fb;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

#name {
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#name a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}

#headerButtons {
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #999;
}

#headerButtons ul {
  margin: 0;
}

#headerButtons li {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-top: 30px
}

#headerButtons a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
}

#headerButtons a:hover>li {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="IMAGES/Logo.svg" width="50px" height="50px">
  </div>
  <div id="name">
    <a href="index.php">
      <p>Project Archive</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="headerButtons">
    <ul>
      <a href="Login.php">
        <li>Register</li>
      </a>
      <a href="Register.php">
        <li>Login</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

> But correct solution according to html specification would be you put
>   all anchor inside the li tag as shown below.

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="IMAGES/Logo.svg" width="50px" height="50px">
  </div>
  <div id="name">
    <a href="index.php">
      <p>Project Archive</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="headerButtons">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="Login.php">
        Register

      </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="Register.php">
        Login
      </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here is a snippet**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f6f4fb;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

#name {
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#name a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}

#headerButtons {
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #999;
}

#headerButtons ul {
  margin: 0;
}

#headerButtons li {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-top: 30px
}

#headerButtons a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
}

#headerButtons a:hover>li {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="IMAGES/Logo.svg" width="50px" height="50px">
  </div>
  <div id="name">
    <a href="index.php">
      <p>Project Archive</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="headerButtons">
    <ul>
      <a href="Login.php">
        <li>Register</li>
      </a>
      <a href="Register.php">
        <li>Login</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<a>` directly inside `<ul>` is invalid HTML.

Comment: Yes, you are correct its incorrect according to the html specification.

Comment: but the answer here shows the reason why it is not working and why the browser is not applying the style.

If you check the answer carefully at the end I added the fact.

Comment: @Xufox I have reformatted my answer to reflect the fact more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `li` tag inside `a` tag, `li` must be inside `ul` tags

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f6f4fb;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

#name {
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#name a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}

#headerButtons {
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #999;
}

#headerButtons ul {
  margin: 0;
}

#headerButtons li {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-top: 30px
}

#headerButtons a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
}

#headerButtons a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="IMAGES/Logo.svg" width="50px" height="50px">
  </div>
  <div id="name">
    <a href="index.php">
      <p>Project Archive</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="headerButtons">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="Login.php">
        Register
        
      </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="Register.php">
        Login
      </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```